Texture / UV not following mesh armature deformation animation
Background
I have a simple tree mesh. This mesh has been UV unwrapped. An armature deformation with automatic weights has been applied to the mesh. That armature has then been animated within Blender. I have also applied a very simple texture shader to the mesh.
The Problem
When the mesh animates, the texture appears to stay in the same place causing an effect whereby the mesh seems to 'move across' the UV / texture. I need the texture to 'follow' the mesh insofar as possible. I suspect this will involve some kind of animation of the UV? [See video for example of problem].
The Questions
How can I go about achieving this? What is the industry standard way to do this with deformations like this? Do I have to animate the UV for every keyframe to match the deformation?
Supporting Media
Video of Issue:
https://youtu.be/Pedv2s47R_M
Armature / UV / Wireframe / Shader:





Your TextureCoordinate node is outputting Object space coordinates. You need to connect UV to that mapping node for it to be reading from your UV map.

I can't believe I didn't see that! Thank you so much. Such a silly mistake!

Thanks to Jakemoyo for the answer.
The issue was that my texture was mapped to object space co-ordinates. Mapping to the UV / Generated coordinates instead as shown below worked as expected as the texture was then being properly mapped.


Don't forget to accept your answer so it removes it from the question queue.

Thanks, I'll come back in two days to accept it as SO won't allow me to accept it earlier.
